# xcode executes code that has been deleted

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

At one point, I modified one piece of code in one of my .m files. The strange thing is that the program runs as if I didn't modify anything. I have deleted some NSLog - lines of code but the console still shows their results (so they - some how- work!!) then I noticed that all I add in this m file has no effect, the executed code being the one before these changes. 
Please help figure out what's going on.      I even commented ApplicationDidLaunch line...and it still work!!!!.

Comment: Stale binaries could be caused by a few things. At the very least, be sure to Clean All from the Build menu, and rebuild and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As quixoto has stated, you can force a clean build by selecting Build -> Clean All.  This option won't be available if you still have your app running in your device or on the simulator, so make sure you have quit the app on whichever device you are testing on.  The option will then be available and you can clean the binaries out and build again afresh.